# postgres remove blank values from grouping

Tags: postgresql

I have a rollup SQL statement that I'm trying to covert over from Oracle into PostGresSql. Overall the results look correct except I'm getting a blank value in the grouping column and I'm not sure how to get rid of it.

Right now I have:

```
SELECT 
         COALESCE(CASE WHEN GROUPING(COUNTY) = 1 THEN 'TOTAL' else county::text END) as COUNTY
        ,COUNT(CASE WHEN STV_TO_GAS THEN 1 END) as STOVE_TO_GAS_SUM
        ,COUNT(CASE WHEN FIRE_TO_GAS THEN 1 END) as FIRE_TO_GAS_SUM
        ,COUNT(CASE WHEN PELLET_TO_GAS THEN 1 END) as PELLET_TO_GAS_SUM
        ,COUNT(CASE WHEN STV_TO_ELECTRIC THEN 1 END) as STOVE_TO_ELECTRIC_SUM
        ,COUNT(CASE WHEN FIRE_TO_ELECTRIC THEN 1 END) as FIRE_TO_ELECTRIC_SUM
        ,COUNT(CASE WHEN PELLET_TO_ELECTRIC THEN 1 END) as PELLET_TO_ELECTRIC_SUM
        ,COUNT(CASE WHEN MERIDIAN THEN 1 END) as WITHIN_MERIDIAN_SUM
        ,count(CASE WHEN hb357.stv_to_gas then 1 END) + 
        count(CASE WHEN hb357.fire_to_gas then 1 END) + 
        count(CASE WHEN hb357.pellet_to_gas then 1 END) + 
        count(CASE WHEN hb357.stv_to_electric then 1 END) + 
        count(CASE WHEN hb357.fire_to_electric then 1 END) + 
        count(CASE WHEN hb357.pellet_to_electric then 1 END) + 
        count(CASE WHEN hb357.meridian then 1 END ) AS county_totals
    FROM woodburn.HB357
    WHERE app_status IN ('pending','approved')
    AND (COUNTY IS NOT NULL OR trim(COUNTY) <> '')
    GROUP BY rollup (county)
```

but its still returning a blank value in the county column

[image]

I've also trued changing the first case statement to

```
COALESCE(CASE 
            WHEN GROUPING(COUNTY) = 1 THEN 'TOTAL' 
            WHEN TRIM(COUNTY) != '' AND COUNTY IS NOT NULL then county
        END) as COUNTY
```

but its returning a null row for county

FINAL SOLUTION

After trying all things suggested I essentially implemented what Jorge Campos recommended by doing the following:

```
SELECT 
         COALESCE(CASE 
            WHEN GROUPING(COUNTY) = 1 THEN 'TOTAL' 
            WHEN TRIM(COUNTY) != '' then county
        END) as COUNTY
        ,COUNT(CASE WHEN STV_TO_GAS THEN 1 END) as STOVE_TO_GAS_SUM
        ,COUNT(CASE WHEN FIRE_TO_GAS THEN 1 END) as FIRE_TO_GAS_SUM
        ,COUNT(CASE WHEN PELLET_TO_GAS THEN 1 END) as PELLET_TO_GAS_SUM
        ,COUNT(CASE WHEN STV_TO_ELECTRIC THEN 1 END) as STOVE_TO_ELECTRIC_SUM
        ,COUNT(CASE WHEN FIRE_TO_ELECTRIC THEN 1 END) as FIRE_TO_ELECTRIC_SUM
        ,COUNT(CASE WHEN PELLET_TO_ELECTRIC THEN 1 END) as PELLET_TO_ELECTRIC_SUM
        ,COUNT(CASE WHEN MERIDIAN THEN 1 END) as WITHIN_MERIDIAN_SUM
        ,count(CASE WHEN hb357.stv_to_gas then 1 END) + 
        count(CASE WHEN hb357.fire_to_gas then 1 END) + 
        count(CASE WHEN hb357.pellet_to_gas then 1 END) + 
        count(CASE WHEN hb357.stv_to_electric then 1 END) + 
        count(CASE WHEN hb357.fire_to_electric then 1 END) + 
        count(CASE WHEN hb357.pellet_to_electric then 1 END) + 
        count(CASE WHEN hb357.meridian then 1 END ) AS county_totals
    FROM woodburn.HB357
    WHERE app_status IN ('pending','approved')
    AND COUNTY IS NOT NULL 
    AND TRIM(COUNTY) != ''
    GROUP BY rollup (county)
```

Comment: Just add the empty as part of your case statement i.e `case when trim(county::text) = '' then 'something'...` for the column you are grouping. Or remove it altogether on the where section ` and trim(count) != '' )

Comment: I just realized that you already have the trim there in the where section. So you need to figure out what exactly is on that field, because i believe the difference here must be on the conversion `county::text` or try adding `trim(county::text) <> ''` on the where

Comment: You can always add `HAVING county <> ''` at the end.

Comment: If I add `HAVING trim(COUNTY) <> ''` the blank values do go away but then so does the TOTAL column for some reason